# async-await / blocking. Am I understanding it correctly?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm struggling to get out of my synchronous way of thinking and keep doing this pattern of programming:

```
async function displayEmailAddy() {
    const userId = await fetchSomethingFromDb()
    const userEmail = getEmailAddy(userId)
}
```

Am I understanding it correctly, that during `userEmail` declaration, the value of `userID` is still `undefined` because it's still probably on await?

Do I need to change the whole paradigm, or just shuffle things around a little bit

Comment: Have you tried it? No, userId will be resolved from fetchSomethingFromDb. Check documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#examples

Comment: No, await "stops" code's execution until promise fulfills.

Comment: so `getEmailAddy(userId)` will not be called until `userId` is resolved?

Comment: You seem to have defined a recursive function in `getEmailAddy` which I assume is a type.  Please correct the question so that we can understand your intent.

Comment: `await` will evaluate the expression that follows it, which will be a promise (or made one), and then the outer function will return (yes!). Code will execute as it would normally after a function returns, until the call stack is empty. If then the promise that is awaited, fulfills, the function's execution context will be restored, and execution will resume with the next statement after `await`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*during declaration*"?

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `await` for `fetchSomethingFromDb` funtion it wouldn't run the next line until the function finishes running. So when the compiler gets to `userEmail` line the `userId` whouldn't be`undefined`. Here is the example that you idea correct:

```
async function displayEmailAddy() {
    const userId = fetchSomethingFromDb()
    const userEmail = getEmailAddy(userId)
}
```

I just removed the await part before `fetchSomethingFromDb` function. This way compiler would run the line after that in parallel with `fetchSomethingFromDb` function.

Comment: In this example the `userId` would be a promise and not `undefined` though

Comment: ok, so anything below `await` will NOT run until the response?

Comment: Yes exactly. It would waits for the await function to finish